# How to check if array result is clicked in php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I check if an array result is clicked. 
Below is my code to iterate through the database.
The problem now is that is not checking to confirm if the result of the array is clicked.

```
  <tr>
    <td><input value=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['subject_id']; ?> type="submit" id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['subject_id']; ?> 
    class="form-control btn btn-success" id="subject_id"> 

      <input name="subject_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['subject_id'];   ?>" /> <?php if(isset($row_Recordset1['subject_id'])) { 
      echo "u are welcome";


   //code...


    } 
    ?></td>

    <td><div><?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?></div></td>
  </tr>
 <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? PHP can never detect clicks, as it does not run in the browser

Comment: Please, don't share code in the comment section. Add it to your question

Comment: thank you for your concern. am working on the school management software using php. i have designed the code that display all subjects and subject ID taken by that teacher in a table. the question is that what code can i use in such a way that if the user click on any subject displayed in the table the code should query the database to display all students offer such subject using the subject id as the primary key. thank you.